# Document event ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to identify specific event on the document in events object. For example

```
$(document).click(function () {
      console.log(1)
});

$(document).click(function () {
      console.log(2)
});

var events = $._data(document, "events");
console.log(events);
```

[image]

And when i log all "click" events, there are no difference between it:

How can i add custom ID to each events? Maybe i can use **namespace** or i can change **guid**?

I need to check: "is the specific event exist?"

Comment: What would an event "existing" mean? It would help if you showed the code using this information that you want to write.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Why exactly do you need to do this?

Comment: I have a script that hangs a click event. And after I need to check exactly this event is exist

Comment: @FeR-S: I'm afraid that doesn't clarify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind and pass argument to the call-back listener to identify the type

```
$(document).click(function (type) {
      console.log(type)
}.bind(this,"i-am-click"));

$(document).click(function (type) {
      console.log(type)
}.bind(this,"i-am-another-click"));

var events = $._data(document, "events");
console.log(events);
```

**UPDATE**

To Identify the specific event object in yours events array you can do the following hack.

```
 $(document).click(
    (function(){
        var fn = function(){  // Your callback function
                      console.log('i-am-click');
                 };

        fn.event_id=1;  // Adding id to the callback.

        return fn;  // returning the function after adding id
    })()
);

$(document).click(
    (function(){
        var fn = function(){  // Your callback function
                      console.log('i-am-another-click');
                 };

        fn.event_id=2;  // Adding id to the callback.

        return fn;  // returning the callback function after adding id
    })()
);

var events = $._data(document, "events");

// Find the events in the event array using filter

// This will return an array of match event with id in events array
events.click.filter(function(ev){return ev.handler.event_id==1;}); // event id you are looking for
```

Comment: thanks for your responce. But how can i use that to check is there "i-am-click" event exist?

`$.each(events, function(i,val) {
     if(...) ...
});`

Comment: Yes, i want to know what **"i-am-another-click"** event handler has been registered. Sorry for my english).

Comment: @FeR-S: It also relies on internals of jQuery that could change from one dot release to the next. If you would answer the questions people ask you, we'd probably be able to help you do this without creating something fragile.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I will describe the tasks more accurately, Thanks for the comment. But **NadirLaskar** guessed what i mean and offered his working decision first.

Answer (score 1):

You've clarified to say:

> I want to know [if the]...event handler has been registered

Use a flag:

```
var handlersRegistered = {};
$(document).click(function() {
    console.log("a");
});
handlersRegistered["a"] = true;

$(document).click(function() {
   console.log("b");
});
handlersRegistered["b"] = true;
```

If at some point you need to know whether handler "a" was registered:

```
if (handlersRegistered["a"]) {
    // Yes it is
} else {
    // No, it isn't
}
```

No need to go mucking about in the internals of jQuery.

(I'm using `handlersRegistered["a"]` rather than `handlersRegistered.a` in case you want to use labels for these that aren't valid identifiers.)

Comment: i thing event registration and variable assignment are not connected in any way. And if there is a chance that the handler of this event will not be registered, this decision is not correct.

Comment: @FeR-S: In the above, they're absolutely related: By the time `handlersRegistered["a"] = true;` is executed, the "a" handler **is** registered. And when the "a" handler is registered, the **very next thing** that happens (cannot be interrupted) is that `handlersRegistered["a"] = true;` is executed.

Comment: But if i will check it in anover place of document where variable `handlersRegistered` is not exist?

Comment: @FeR-S: Scope `handlersRegistered` like any other variable: As narrowly as possible, but not more so. So if it needs to be in scope for the other code, make sure it is.